# How to create angular 2 component into Nativescript Application?

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm using nativescript with angular 2.

I'm wondering how to rapidly create a ng component in a Nativescript Project.
For example into Angular 2 to create a component we are using `ng generate component hello`.

Is there a nativescript cli solution for that?

Comment: You can look at https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/225

Comment: is that really what im looking for? I can't see something to create component.

Comment: I think my answer should be marked as accepted as it answers your question directly: How can I use `ng generate component` in my NativeScript app.

Comment: I found work solution  " With the help of the NativeScript Schematics, you can also reap the benefits of the Angular CLI in your Angular NativeScript projects." 
https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tooling/angular-cli#installation

And also go follow this 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nativescript/schematics

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A more accurate answer for 2019 (from a file called `adding-Angular-CLI-to-NativeScript.md` in the `@nativescript/schematics` package):

## Adding Angular CLI to a NativeScript project.

1. Add `angular.json` to the project root, with the following content

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@nativescript/schematics"
  },
  "projects": {
    "my-project-name": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": ".",
       "projectType": "application",
       "prefix": "app"
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "my-project-name"
}
```

You can update `my-project-name` to the actual name of your project, but that is not absolutely necessary.

2. Install Angular CLI

```sh
npm i --save-dev @angular/cli
```

3. Install NativeScript Schematics

```sh
npm i --save-dev @nativescript/schematics
```

You can now use Angular CLI commands in your NativeScript project:

```
ng generate component hello-world
```

Comment: follow this same https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nativescript/schematics

Comment: This made things easy for me

Comment: For me it gives error: `An unhandled exception occurred: NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID`

Answer (score 8):

You can use https://github.com/sebawita/nativescript-angular-cli

To generate a component, run:

```
tns generate component <component-name>
tns g c <component-name>
```

To create a component inside a module, run:

```
tns generate component <component-name> <module-name>
tns g c <component-name> <module-name>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 7):

The base command for creating a NativeScript app comes with some predefined templates. For creating base Angular-2 Application you can use

```
tns create myApp --ng
```

Or you can create your own template like this one and pass it as a param

```
tns create myApp --template path-to-template-here
```

Or if you are using VSCode as your IDE for development then you can add the [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=joshdsommer.vscode-add-angular-native-files)

And then it is pretty straight forward: right click on app folder >> ***Add Angular2 Files***

The command will prompt for a name and will generate the following (if the name provided is `home`)

```
home/home.component.ts
home/home.component.html
home/home.component.css
home/home.component.spec.ts
```

Comment: Hi @Nick, I am having doubt. I have downloaded my sample [ NS + angular] project from Playground. In that downloaded file, platforms were empty. I have tried to add iOS platform by using, **tns platform add ios** and opened Xcode.proj, **app** folder  and **.plist** file were missing. Do u know about this issue? Can u guide me on this?

Comment: The link to the vs code extension was very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

**Install Angular CLI**

You should be using @angular/cli@6.1.0 or newer.

```
npm i -g @angular/cli
```

**Install NativeScript Schematics**

```
npm i -g @nativescript/schematics
```

**Prerequisites for using @nativescript/schematics in an existing project**

You need to add an angular.json configuration file to your NativeScript project root directory. That will allow you to use Angular CLI for generating components.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@nativescript/schematics"
  },
  "projects": {
    "project-name": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": ".",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "project-name"
}
```

**Note**: If you created your project with ng new, your project already has angular.json.

**Generate angular.json**

You can generate it the configuration using Schematics.

Install Schematics globally

```
npm install -g @angular-devkit/schematics-cli
```

From inside your project call:

```
schematics @nativescript/schematics:angular-json --name=project-name
```

**Generating Components, Modules, Directives, etc.**

You can use the ng generate (or just ng g) command to generate pretty much any Angular building unit - components, modules, directives, classes and so on. For the full list, check out the Angular CLI [repo](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#generating-components-directives-pipes-and-services).

Some of these generators are overwritten in NativeScript Schematics to suite the needs of a NativeScript Angular application.

**To generate a component**, call:

```
ng g c component-name
```

**To generate a module**, call:

```
ng g m module-name
```

**To generate a component in an existing module folder**, call:

```
ng g c module-name/component-name
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use vs code extention if you are using vs code
from the market place:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wwwalkerrun.nativescript-ng2-snippets

Answer (score -1):

If you get this error: `An unhandled exception occurred: NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID` run generate command with --skip-import

```
ng g c component-name --skip-import
```